# How to create normal registration form in Sitecore MVC using controller Rendering?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I am a fresher to Sitecore MVC. I have been searching in google for the last two days for a simple registration form example in Sitecore MVC, but until now, I didn't find any. Please help me to find this.

Comment: Is the Sitecore Web Forms for Marketers module useful for you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find any boilerplate code to do what you're looking for, but it shouldn't be too hard to put the pieces together yourself. I'd recommend starting with Martina Welander's excellent blog posts and videos on Sitecore MVC, including the 2-part posts on [View renderings](http://mhwelander.net/2014/05/28/posting-forms-in-sitecore-mvc-part-1-view-renderings/) and [Controller renderings](http://mhwelander.net/2014/05/30/posting-forms-in-sitecore-mvc-part-2-controller-renderings/).

Once you've got a good handle on how Sitecore handles MVC architecture, the building blocks you're likely to need will be:

- A controller (eg AccountController)
- An action method on your new controller (eg UserRegistration) marked
  with HttpPost (plus a counterpart for the initial GET request which
  renders the empty form)
- A view model (eg UserRegistrationViewModel)
- A Sitecore layout which acts as the view (eg UserRegistration.cshtml)

How you structure your layouts will depend on your site architecture, so it's difficult to be more specific, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.